# how to load different image to different button without creating multiple database in android studio?

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanted to have multiple image button, where when we click on the image 
   button, it will display different product item. However in order to do that i
   have to create one database each for the image button. So let say i have 8 
   image button i have to create 8 database. I try to create just one database 
   by sorting the item based on categories, but whenever i point to the database 
   it will display all item. What should i do?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:src="@drawable/fashion"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:src="@drawable/book"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the sqlite demo activity where i get my picture from mobile phone category and i will manually insert its detail.

```
  case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();

            if (extras2 != null) {
                Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                // convert bitmap to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
                // Inserting Contacts
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addContact(new Contact("bonamana", "RM20.60","books", 
    "What the heck", imageInByte));
                Intent i = new Intent(SQLiteDemoActivity1.this,
                        SQLiteDemoActivity1.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

            break;
    }
  }
```

This is the display image activity where i get the information i want to
   display from the database

```
  List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()+ " Price: 
   " + cn.getPrice() +" Categories: " + cn.getCategories()
                + " Description: " + cn.getDescription() + " ,Image: " + 
   cn.getImage();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Result: ", log);
        // add contacts data in arrayList
        imageArry.add(cn);
```

This is the database where i store my information.

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "imagedb1";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts1";


// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String CATEGORIES = "categories";
private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";

public DataBaseHandler1(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+ KEY_PRICE + " TEXT," + CATEGORIES + " TEXT,"
            + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"+ KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

public// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact._name); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, contact._price); // Contact Name
    values.put(CATEGORIES, contact._categories); // Contact Name
    values.put(DESCRIPTION, contact._description); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact._image); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    //String selectQuery = "SELECT  id,name,price,image FROM contacts WHERE categories = 'fashion' ORDER BY name";
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts1 WHERE categories = 'books' ORDER BY name";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setCategories(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setDescription(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(5));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // close inserting data from database
    db.close();
    // return contact list
    return contactList;

}
```

}

Comment: I am able to display the picture already. However, i face a major problem. As shown in the picture attach, i have 8 image button which i am going to display my picture based on categories. The picture i will be insert from my mobile phone and the information i will manually insert it one by one from the code.

Comment: At first i try to create 1 database to store all info, however it still display all my picture even though i write sort by categories. Maybe because i will write all my button point to the database java file and at that time it wrote sort by book, so all my button are sort by book. Therefore, in the end i created 8 database for 8 buttons. It solve my problem at first but when i want to search for product or perform add to cart, its impossible to do it simultaneously to 8 database.

Comment: Is there any solution to make it into 1 database or can search or add to cart function perform on 8 database simultaneously?